# error when generate entity in Symfony3 how to solve it

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am a beginner  in Symfony . I used Symfony 3, php 7.3 and Acquia devdesktop as a Server ..
I tried to create database by write this codes in terminal

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

then I generate the entity

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

but after I do that this error appeared

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                                         
  Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?
```

Answer (score 0):

somewhere in your project you are using construction like:

```
switch ($i) {
    case 'test':
        ...
        continue;
```

try to replace `continue` statement by `break`

PS: usually Symfony says in which file the error occurred, it may help in the search

Comment: I check all the project my code that I wrote it do not have (switch ). but in composer.phar file there (switch )but they used (break) > is there any way to solve this problem

Comment: @HaifaNaif try to search by `continue` statement.
Could you provide full symfony exception?